# Issue with Expo Image Picker at build time

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-image-picker

This is the error I am facing at the time of building the ios for my expo app.
[image]

Here is the code for Image Picker I used [image]

This is working great in my simulator expo app as well as in iphone expo as well but giving this error while building using eas build -p=ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try doing different things and after trying many things I get to know it's because of outdated verions I updated everything in my package.json with the help of expo doctor I see compatible and install them and it's fixed.